# Copy a file every n seconds in python

Tags: python

With this code, I look at a source directory and copy it to the destination. But when I add a new file to the source directory, the copying is not done. And I want a file to be copied every second. This code is doing batch copying. Can you help me solve these two problems?

```
import os,os.path
import shutil
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

my_path = 'source_path'
target = 'target_path'


onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(my_path ) if isfile(join(my_path , f))]

while True:
    for file in onlyfiles:
        if file.endswith(".gz"):           
            a = my_path + file
            b = target + file
            shutil.copy(a, b)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You need to place **onlyfiles** statement inside while loop

Comment: move the assignment of `onlyfiles` into the `while True:` loop. Of course it will re-copy all the old files as well (not sure you want that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, this solution can make it work

```
import shutil
import time
from pathlib import Path
import glob

my_path = 'source_path'
target = 'target_path'

onlyfiles = glob.glob(my_path+'/*.gz')

for file in onlyfiles:
    shutil.copy(file,  target + '/'+ Path(file).name)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: let me know if the code works

Answer (score 2):

onlyfiles list is created before file copy loop. If you add a new file it won't be updated. Move it after sleep(1) line and it should work as you want.

Answer (score 1):

First off you can use libraries like `shutil` that has `copytree` to copy a directory.

Second, you might want to use another library, `watchdog`, to look for new file events and then copy only the new incoming files.

Answer (score 1):

Try put this inside the loop because the variable have the assignment only in the first time and never change after that.

```
import os,os.path
import shutil
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

my_path = 'source_path'
target = 'target_path'    

while True:
    # refresh every time 
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(my_path ) if isfile(join(my_path , f))]

    for file in onlyfiles:
        if file.endswith(".gz"):           
            a = my_path + file
            b = target + file
            shutil.copy(a, b)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Copying the new files with this development, thank you. But there is still a bulk copy. I want only one file to be copied per second. Can you help with this?

Comment: hey added the answer below, let me know if that works

Comment: Try add a time.sleep(1000)